# Apps Script to JSON Date Time Format Problem

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, date-formatting

I have a Google Sheet where column 'A' is a date Time column. [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e3zXqkXQlaMOdnLQck4PyinR84Y78vOallUveFosLwU/edit?usp=sharing)

i converted this Google sheet file to JSON Data. [Link](https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=WBgxlSYqdQ7ANDYg-D-hBcYtoUhmNTUC43bdzHUytgIFmg3lJ-tLxOHmLRin2YO6L7Su3viNWnXhk70tRm5gc_U9ssog_VXbm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnMs1tm11-lp-Q13okfTSX_i5IzvU5JZnhqqg8H90dlfD5jU3SrNArGaMaXSvzMBh2h5A-lJ1RFia7VipeMnCxQqExfB7Qd_-iQ&lib=MVoeqw6DJ9bzix14T3i_S_jbsQ0CRhLAj)

from this JSON data is fetching my website page in a table. [Link](http://123moviesflix.pw/fetch.php)

The Problem with date is it's showing **17/01/2023 19:47:35** To **2023-01-17T14:17:35.270Z**
How can I make this **Readable**

My Apps Script Code is below

```
function doGet(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var nse = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = [];
var rlen = nse.getLastRow();
var clen = nse.getLastColumn();
var rows = nse.getRange (1,1, rlen, clen).getValues(); 
for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var datarow = rows[i];
  var record = {};
for(var j=0; j < clen ; j++){ 
  record[rows[0][j]] = datarow[j];
    }
    data.push(record);
  }
  var result = JSON.stringify(data);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

and My Javascript code is here.

```html
<section>
        <h1>My Google Sheet Table</h1>
  
        <!-- TABLE CONSTRUCTION-->
        <table id='mytable'>
            <!-- HEADING FORMATION -->
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Months</th>
            </tr>
  
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
  
                    // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
                   $.getJSON("JsonDataLink", 
                            function (data) {
                        var content = '';
  
                        // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
  
                            //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
                            // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
                            content += '<tr>';
                            content += '<td>' + 
                                value.DATE + '</td>';
  
                            content += '<td>' + 
                                value.Name + '</td>';
  
                            content += '<td>' + 
                                value.Phone + '</td>';
  
                            content += '<td>' + 
                                value.Months + '</td>';
  
                            content += '</tr>';
                        });
                          
                        //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE 
                        $('#mytable').append(content);
                    });
                    
                });
                
            </script>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While links to external resources might be helpful, please bear in mind that questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this, please [edit] the question add the relevant part of the link resourses, i.e. describe the spreadsheet structure and add some sample data as text showing the how the values are displayed in the cells and in the the formula bar. Also you should add a a brief description of your search efforts to find helpful content from this site. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the values of the column "A" of "DATE" are the date object. In this case, how about modifying it as follows?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, only Google Apps Script is modified.

#### IMPORTANT:

**As an important point, in your provided sample Spreadsheet, there are 2 functions of `doGet`. In this case, the expected result might not be able to be obtained. So, please remove one of the 2 `doGet` functions and please modify it as follows.**

#### Modified script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nse = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = [];
  var rlen = nse.getLastRow();
  var clen = nse.getLastColumn();
  var rows = nse.getRange(1, 1, rlen, clen).getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var datarow = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
      record[rows[0][j]] = datarow[j];
    }
    data.push(record);
  }
  var result = JSON.stringify(data);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, only Google Apps Script is modified. In this modification, the date object retrieved by `getValues` is formatted.

#### From:

```
record[rows[0][j]] = datarow[j];
```

#### To:

```
record[rows[0][j]] = j == 0 ? Utilities.formatDate(datarow[j], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") : datarow[j];
```

- Please modify the format for your actual situation.

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, only Javascript is modified. In this modification, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is used. You can see it with as `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js` of CDN.

Please modify your Javascript as follows.

#### From:

```
content += '<td>' + 
    value.DATE + '</td>';
```

#### To:

```
content += '<td>' + 
    moment(new Date(value.DATE)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') + '</td>';
```

- Please modify the format for your actual situation.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)